# Typescript inherit a variable from superclass

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have 2 components:

```
export class BaseComponent {
    succesfullSave: boolean;
}


export class InheritComponent extends BaseComponent {
    isButtonDisabled() {
        return !super.succesfullSave;
    }
}
```

in my InheritComponent html, I have a button with a disabled directive:

```
<button [disabled]="isButtonDisabled()"></button>
```

After changing the `succesfullSave` property value, the button is still enabled.

Angular doesn't look for value change when inheriting a value from superclass?

Comment: Did you check if isButtonDisabled() is actually being called?

Comment: it is called for sure

Answer (score 1):

disable attribute accepts a value not a functional. So i think creating a get property would a solve the issue.

```
get isButtonDisabled():boolean=>!super.succesfullSave;
```

Comment: thanks I will try it

Answer (score 1):

Should be just `this.succesfullSave`.

You need `super.` to access a method of your base class, but you have overridden it in your child (extending) class.